# ReST: how can client tell server to return `Content-disposition: attachment`

Tags: rest, csv

So lets say I have a resource at /things.

1. If client does `GET /things/myid` I'll serve the default response (json).
2. If client passes an `Accept: csv` header I will serve the response as csv.

But what if I want to enable the client to tell the server to include a `Content-disposition: attachment` header in the response (to force a download)?